# In a GWT UiBinder template with an image resource, where should I locate the actual image file?

Tags: gwt, uibinder, clientbundle

According to the [docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html), you can add an image resource to be used in a uibinder template like this:

```
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {

  @Source("Logo.jpg")
  ImageResource logo();

  ...
}
```

Using this example as is, however, the image file (Logo.jpg) must be included in the same directory/package as Resources.java. Where should I put my image file and how should I list the file path so that I don't have to keep the image file in my src tree? Specifically, I'm using maven - don't I want my images in src/main/webapp, not in src/main/java/com/mygwtapp/client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a relative path for your images like this:

```
@Source("../../resources/images/Logo.jpg")
ImageResource logo();
```

The path is relative to where your Resources interface is located.
And ../ stands for parent directory.